# Argument grouping in bash scripts

Tags: bash, function, arguments, global

I have a `bash` script with a lot of `functions` that process all arguments received by the script. The problem is, if I use `myfunction $@` or `myfunction $*`, the arguments that contain space characters will be interpreted the wrong way, so I have to use `myfunction "$1" "$2" "$3" ...`, which is immature and limits the number of arguments to 9. Is there a way to solve this problem, perhaps by somehow making received arguments `global`? Or is there some other trick that makes this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use quotes to prevent this.

Examples :

```
test() {
    for i in "$@"
    do
        echo "$i"
    done
}

test "$@"
```

Output :

```
$ ./test.sh foo "bar baz"
foo
bar baz
```

---

**Without quotes :**

```
test() {
    for i in $@ # no quotes
    do
        echo "$i"
    done
}

test "$@"
```

Output :

```
$ ./test.sh foo "bar baz"
foo
bar
baz
```

Or

```
test() {
    for i in "$@"
    do
        echo "$i"
    done
}

test $@ # no quotes
```

Output :

```
$ ./test.sh foo "bar baz"
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the `function` keyword to define functions. Your function should be defined as `test() { ...`.